# Load HTML Object once and use multiple times

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to load a single SVG file as an HTML Object tag multiple times, and I'm using JavaScript to write the HTML responsible for the placement of the Objects. However, each time the JavaScript writes to the page, the Object loads a separate copy.

Is there a way to load it once and then reference that copy multiple times?

Here's an example of what I'm doing (assume the javascript is being called after the div has been loaded.):

```js
(function(){
  var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
  var numberOfElements = 10;
  for(var i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++){
    foo.innerHTML +=
            "<object height=\"10px\" width=\"10px\" data=\"someSVG.svg\"></object>";
  }
}())
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="foo">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might show us some code.

Comment: It's common browser behaviour - I guess. Your "foo.innerHTML" tells the browser: Something in the DOM changed. Please validate, reference and rendert it instantly. In your case... 10 times.

Comment: Same behaviour occurs, when you hard code 10x of this object to the source code. So it has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Just add all our HTML-code at once.
Otherwise you tell the browser 10 times, there are changes in the DOM and it starts to validate, reference and rendert it instantly.
Hopefully this will use the browsers file cache for 'someSVG.svg'

```js
(function() {
  var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
  var numberOfElements = 10;
  var content = ""; // temporary string, starting empty
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
    content += 
      '<object height="10px" width="10px" data="http://www.webmasterpro.de/coding/article/svg.html/image/600px-SVG-Logo2.svg.png/scale/100x150/"></object>';
  }
  foo.innerHTML += content; // append once, outside of loop
}())
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Comment: Ok. I updated it and now it starts with an empty string. The prior version concatenated an 'undefined' variable with the '<object...>' strings. Now, with the HTML-snippet, the code demo above runs.

Comment: I guess I should be more specific. I did catch that error and implemented your code correctly to begin with. It still loaded the objects separately all 10 times.

Comment: Also, that image in your updated code is actually a png.

Comment: You are right. Even if I do: 1.insert one instance, 2. select this DOM element ( var element = document.querySelector( '#foo object' );), 3. clone this element and append to #foo (foo.appendChild( element.cloneNode( true ) );) , even then the browser loads the data source again and again... :-(

Comment: :/ That's annoying. Oh well. I think I can come up with a work-around for my specific case, but it would be great if there was a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to occur due to  element.
If you switch to an , which also can handle SVGs. It works like a charm and uses the cached src.

Can you?

```
   foo.innerHTML += '<img height="10px" width="10px" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/WWF_logo.svg"/>'
```

See this snippet:

```js
(function() {
  var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
  var numberOfElements = 10;
  var content = ""; // temporary string, starting empty
  content +=
    '<img height="10px" width="10px" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/WWF_logo.svg"/>';
  foo.innerHTML += content; // append once, outside of loop
  var element = document.querySelector('#foo img');
  for (var i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
    foo.appendChild(element.cloneNode(true));
  }
}())
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```